# Adding multiple Variables on println

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Numbers
    int operand1 = 25;
    int operand2 = 6;

    //Arithmetic values
    int sum = 0;
    int difference = 0;
    int product = 0;
    int quotient = 0;
    int remainder = 0;

    //Operations
    sum = operand1 + operand2;
    difference = operand1 - operand2;
    product = operand1*operand2;
    quotient = operand1/operand2;
    remainder = operand1%operand2;

    //Output
    System.out.println("Arithmetic");
    System.out.println("============================");
    System.out.println("25 + 6 = " + sum);
    System.out.println("25 - 6 = " + difference);
    System.out.println("25 * 6 = " + product);
    System.out.println("25 / 6 = " + quotient);
    System.out.println("25 % 6 = " + remainder);
```

I'm trying to find a way to replace "25 + 6", "25 - 6", etc... with variables like
(operand1 "+" operand2 "=" sum) so the values will change dynamically depending on what value I put on oeprand1 and operand2. Is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, just use more string concatenation.

Comment: You already did it for sum, difference, product,.. Why would it be different for operand1 and operand2?

Comment: Your question demonstrates that you already know how to do this.  Please try harder, before you post something here.

Answer (score 5):

You do it the same exact way you are inserting your result variables into the strings...

```
System.out.println(operand1 + " + " + operand2 + " = " + sum);
```

You could also use `printf` if you wanted to although you have to insert the line break explicitly:

```
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", operand1, operand2, sum);
```

Comment: Ohh... I was adding exta +... My bad

Comment: Can you use the `printf` to repeat variables in the same statement like `MessageFormat.format`'s {#} syntax?

Comment: @CodeCamper Yes, you can specify positional parameters; see the *Argument Index* section of the [format string description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). E.g. `printf("%1$d %2$d %1$d", 88, 99)` outputs `88 99 88`.

Comment: @JasonC Awesome! Now I guess I will only use `MessageFormat.format` for when I need to store it in a string.

Comment: @CodeCamper Don't forget about [`String.format()`](http://bit.ly/1paUSbj), which uses the same format string style. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just me but I find this to look much cleaner.

```
System.out.print(MessageFormat.format(
"Arithmetic\n" + 
"============================\n"+
"{0} + {1} = {2}\n"+
"{0} - {1} = {3}\n"+
"{0} * {1} = {4}\n"+
"{0} / {1} = {5}\n"+
"{0} % {1} = {6}\n", operand1,operand2,sum,difference,product,quotient,remainder));
```

The `MessageFormat.format` provides a neat alternative way to accomplish what you are looking for.

Remember sometimes *less* is more! Why repeat the print command over and over again?

Comment: +1 This works too, it really depends on how fine of a grain of control you want; for example, you may not want to print the division result line if `operand2` is 0. You probably want to use whatever line separator the current platform uses, by the way; not sure if `MessageFormat` supports that automatically (maybe it does?). Consider using `print` as well (conceptually, it's a bit odd to mix `println` with a string containing line breaks) -- `println` conveys the intention that you mean to print a single line.

Comment: @JasonC I am not sure if it fixes the new line. Probably not :( Edited my weird println habit away.